# Facebook PHP SDK 4.0 - Cannot re-ask read permissions once denied

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm currently asking users for two read permissions i.e. `email` and `user_location` and one write permssion i.e. `publish_actions`. Following is the code snippet I'm using to verify if the user has granted all requested permissions:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID, APP_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);

    if ( $facebook->IsAuthenticated() ) {

        // Verify if all of the scopes have been granted
        if ( !$facebook->verifyScopes( unserialize(SCOPES) ) ) {
            header( "Location: " . $facebook->getLoginURL( $facebook->denied_scopes) );
            exit;
        }
        ...
    }
```

`Facebook` is a class I've customly built to wrap the login flow used by various classes in the SDK. `IsAuthenticated()` makes the use of `code` get variable to check if the user is authorized. `verifyScopes()` checks granted permissions against `SCOPES` and assings an array of denied scopes to `denied_scopes` property. getLoginURL()` builds a login-dialog URL based on permissions passed as an an array as a only paramter.

Now, the problem is when the user doesn't grant write permissions, `publish_actions` in this case, write permission dialog is shown until user grants the write permission. But if the user chooses to deny of the read permissions, say `email`, the read login dialog isn't show. Instead Facebook redirects to the callback URL (that is `REDIRECT_URI`) creating a redirect loop.

The application I'm builiding requires `email` to be compulsorily provided but apparently the above approach (which seems to be the only) is failing. So, is there a workaround or a alternative way to achieve this? Or Facebook doesn't allow to ask for read permissions once denied?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0#re-asking-declined-permissions

Comment: @CBroe but write permissions seem to not require `auth_type` to be added. :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of *July 15, 2014*, [an update](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/commit/a0508f4fb01aa8d72c35ededd5d536f3ce12233c) has been made to the *Facebook PHP SDK 4.x* that allows user to re-ask the declined permissions. The function prototype of `getLoginUrl()` now looks like this.

```
public function getLoginUrl($redirectUrl, $scope = array(), $rerequest = false, $version = null)
```

So, to re-ask declined permissions we'd do something like this:

```
<?php
// ...

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper();

if ($PermissionIsDeclined) {
    header("Location: " . $helper->getLoginUrl( $redirect_uri, $scopes, true );
    exit;
}

// ....
?>
```

Comment: It looks like as of today, this update is still only on the dev branch and not master(?). I was confused a bit at first as to why I couldnt add the rerequest 'true' param. Someone who wants to use this solution would have to make sure they are grabbing the dev branch of the facebook php sdk

Comment: @Eddie Yeah. Turns out the change was made to 4.1 in-development branch. And the order of parameters would be a breaking change in 4.0.x. The SDK is being refactored. So, lets hope for to get more sleek version of the SDK soon.

Answer (score 2):

For the time being you can append &auth_type=rerequest to the getLoginUrl return value to enable a rerequest, kind of lame but it works.

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($app_url, $app_id, $app_secret);
$login  = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'user_likes', 'user_location'));
print $login."&auth_type=rerequest";
```

Answer (score 1):

what about `getReRequestUrl();` ?
That works just fine.
Read more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/5.0.0