# Length of param app_id must be less than or equal to 32

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I'm writing a Facebook login integration using the PHP SDK and running into the above error.

On our main page we have the following code to request `public_profile` and `email`.

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{our_app_id}',
  'app_secret' => '{our_app_secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4']);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['public_profile', 'email'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://oursiteurl/includes/fbcallback.php/', 
  $permissions);
```

This code pops open a new window, processes the Facebook login, authorizes the app permissions, and sends us back to `fbcallback.php`. Users can disallow revealing their email to our app, but our app absolutely must have being email. So `fbcallback.php` evaluates whether or not we received the email. If it did we enter a new record in our database; if not, I want it to present an option to rerequest the email permissions. For this I'm trying the following:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '{our_app_id}',
    'app_secret' => '{our_app_secret}',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4']);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['public_profile', 'email'];
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
$redirect = "http://media.pvplive.com/includes/fbcallback.php/";
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect, $permissions, TRUE);
```

Basically, I'm looping back to `fbcallback.php`, but this time with the `rerequest` flag set to `TRUE`. I receive no complaints on landing on `fbcallback.php` the first time, but when I click on the link for the new `$loginUrl` it throws the following error:

`Length of param app_id must be less than or equal to 32`

I haven't been able to find any answers explaining this error yet or what needs to be corrected to get rid of it. I'm using the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716168/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-cannot-re-ask-read-permissions-once-denied/24725375#24725375) for code for rerequesting permissions already denied using the PHP SDK.

Comment: And the length of `'{our_app_id}'` is...? (`var_dump(strlen('{our_app_id}'));`)

Comment: It's 16 characters, hard-coded into that new `Facebook\Facebook` instance. I blanked it here for security.

Comment: Do you know which line is causing the failure? If it accepts the ID when creating `$fb`, but then throws the error when creating `$helper`, this would be important to know.

Comment: The problematic line appears to be `$loginUrl`. More specifically, when I add `TRUE` after the permissions attribute. I found this when I added `TRUE` to my original main page code to test and I started to get the same error. As far as I can tell I am using that parameter correctly.